# Seg Fault Using a Struct in Shared Memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

I apologize in advance for my ignorance, this is giving me a lot more trouble than it should, but I've been banging my head into my desk for hours trying to come up with what I'm doing wrong.  I want to write an application that has shared memory storing a struct.  For some reason, I can't get off the ground to start, I keep getting a seg fault from accessing the members of my struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE 10

struct shared_data
{
    long sequence[10];
    int sequence_size;
};
typedef struct shared_data shared_data;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
    int segment_id;

    shared_data * shared_memory;

    segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(shared_data), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    shared_memory = (shared_data *) shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);

    shared_memory->sequence_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("\n\nSequence Size: %d\n\n",shared_memory->sequence_size);

    shmdt(shared_memory);
}
```

UPDATE:  Thanks everyone, my system administrator was running diagnostics and somehow disabled shared memory.

Comment: I just tried the code you posted, and it compiled and ran fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't look to bad to me. The only obvious thing missing is some kind of check for the number of arguments passed like:

```
if (argc != 2)
  return 1;
```

Is it possible you just missed to call your program with an argument. In this case it would be

```
atoi (argv[1])
```

that leads to your segfault.

BTW: additionally checking return values of `shmget` and `shmat` might be a good idea too.

Comment: Ah, good point, when I ran the code I just passed an argument, assuming OP was doing that too.

Comment: While I missed it in my first attempt :) as OP probably is missing too.

Comment: And keep in mind atoi() is deprecated.  Take a look at strtol() instead.